# Details about Promises; examples

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, callback, bluebird

I struggle to implement Promises. (I *think* I understand them, but I get unexpected outcomes frequently, so maybe I don't.)

Consider this code, please.

```
function ap() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('function ap starting   want this');
    function ender() {
      console.log('function ender starting   want this');
      return resolve('ender');
      console.log('after return in ender   don\'t want this'); //#1
    }
    ender()
    console.log('after function ender and its resolve ' +
      'for Promise   don\'t want this'); //#2
  }) // Promise
} // ap

console.log('---')
ap()
.then(function(result, error) {
  if (error) console.log ('error ' + error.message)
  console.log('function ap result   result=' + result +
    '   want this')
})
```

I've included console.log statements lots of places and indicated whether I want them to print, given my understanding of promises.

I expected:

```
function ap starting   want this
function ender starting   want this
function ap result   result=ender   want this
```

I didn't want the last call to console.log inside ender (//#1) because it's after a return sufficient to get me out of ender scope. My linter claimed it is "unreachable"; sounds consistent.

I didn't want the console call after the ender call (//#2) because ender, after all, resolved the Promise which is virtually all of the ap scope; it'd be no surprise to exit the promise and exit ap.

I got:

```
function ap starting   want this
function ender starting   want this
after function ender and its resolve for Promise   don't want this
function ap result   result=ender   want this
```

Question: Is this the right lesson? The language doesn't recognize the prominence of the Promise in ap scope. The "return" was sufficient to leave ender scope, but not ap scope. The "resolve('ender')" was sufficient to resolve the promise. An execution chain continued after the ender call, which is why the unwanted statement printed. Programmers must *both* send callback functions to the Promise *and* get out of the scope of the enclosing function.

Proceeding on the assumption that's true, I wrote this code.

```
function bp() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('function bp starting   want this')
    function ender() {
      console.log('function ender starting   want this');
      return resolve('ender');
      console.log('after return in ender   don\'t want this');
    }
    ender(); return;
    console.log('after function ender and its resolve ' +
      'for Promise   don\'t want this');
  }) // Promise
} // bp
```

It's different from the first code only in that I added a return immediately after the ender call. The only path through ender includes "return resolve('ender')"; if I add "return" immediately after the ender call, it'll get me out of bp scope and all might be well.

Allowing for a different function name, I expected the same result as I had previously expected and got that result. Seems like my "lesson learned" might be close to the right answer.

Next I wrote this code (please ignore references to j; they're distraction; I thought I needed them for a follow-on question, but that didn't work the first time, making this post shorter!):

```
function cp(i, j) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('function cp starting         i=' + i +
      '   j=' + j + '   want this');
    function ender() {
      console.log('function cp ender starting   i=' + i +
        '   j=' + j + '   want this');
      i++;
      let reps = 3;
      if (i < reps) {
        cp(i, j)
        .then(function(result, error) {
          if (error) {
            console.log('*** error   i=' + i +
              '   j=' + j + '   msg=' + error.message +
              '   want this');
            return reject(error);
          }
          console.log('in cp   cp('+ i + ', ' + j +
            ')     result=' + result + '   want this');
          return resolve(result);
        }) // cp(i) callback
        console.log('in cp   i=' + i + '   j=' + j + '' +
          '   in ender after reject, resolve, and ' +
          'callback   don\'t want this'); //#3
      } // if (i < reps)
      console.log('in cp   resolving   i=' + i +
          '   j=' + j + '      want this')
      return resolve('done');
    } // ender
    ender(); return;
    console.log('in cp   i=' + i + '   j=' + j +
      '   after ender call and return for cp scope' +
      '   don\'t want this');
  }) // Promise
} // cp
```

It adds recursion and immediately follows the ender call with "return"; it removes the unreachable code the linter identified; all might go well.

I got

```
function cp starting         i=0   j=0   want this
function cp ender starting   i=0   j=0   want this
function cp starting         i=1   j=0   want this
function cp ender starting   i=1   j=0   want this
function cp starting         i=2   j=0   want this
function cp ender starting   i=2   j=0   want this
in cp   resolving   i=3   j=0      want this
in cp   i=2   j=0   in ender after return, resolve, and callback   don't want this
in cp   resolving   i=2   j=0      want this
in cp   i=1   j=0   in ender after return, resolve, and callback   don't want this
in cp   resolving   i=1   j=0      want this
in cp   cp(2, 0)     result=done   want this
in cp   cp(1, 0)     result=done   want this
function cp result   result=done   want this
```

That's what I expected to get, except that //#3 prints because the language doesn't recognize that all possibilities were covered by either "reject" or by "resolve" within the callback block; it continued executing commands unwisely put in that position.

These code bits are models of a program I continue to have trouble with. Soon, I hope to be able to model other behavior that surprises me.

At a more general level: What do first timers with Promises often fail to understand about Promises? How can we have higher confidence we'll properly control the flow of execution? What resources are especially useful to explain at this level of detail? I'll appreciate any advice on this more general level.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: OMG ,serioursly ???  try to post relevant details bro not entire story.

Comment: Why do you even use `j`?

Comment: Questions like ***What do first timers with Promises often fail to understand about Promises?*** are far too broad for Stack Overflow.  One could write a book or very long article about that topic.  This site works best with a succinct question that has a clear answer in a few paragraphs that is not primarily opinion-based.  In addition asking for 3rd party resources is considered **off-topic** for Stack Overflow.  This question needs to be cleaned up considerably or closed.

Comment: The question is not that broad. It just needs a little patience in order to read it throughout. I've written twice longer questions. Come on guys! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The true answer here is that *reject* and *resolve* are **simply callbacks** and mark the reject/resolve of a Promise. They don't modify the original JavaScript way of working, which is your assumption "*I didn't want the console call after the ender call because ender (//#2), after all, resolved the Promise which is virtually all of the ap scope; it'd be no surprise to exit the promise and exit ap.*"

Calling `reject` or `resolve` simply means you will work with that promise. It doesn't mean the function in which you do so will exit right away. So **for sure** if you want to do so - use `return`.

And it's the very same with your next example:

```
if (i < reps) {
    cp(i, j)
    .then(...)

    console.log(... // you DON'T want this
}
```

Well yeah, for sure you will get it despite you don't want it. You created an `if` statement, in which you do some Promise magic, and then use `console.log`. So JavaScript doesn't care if it's Promise or not - it simply executes things one after another.

If you read a little bit more about Promises, you will understand that they are pure JavaScript, with a `try-catch` inside them, so that if an error is thrown, they can catch it and call the failure callback (usually provided with `.catch(function(err){})`).

Again - Promises **do not modify the way JavaScript works!** And everything you've said is very logical and should indeed happen that exact way. And it's because you expect Promises to block your other code, which won't happen at all :)

Comment: Thanks tons for both the tolerance and the answer. I'm having serious trouble understanding unexpected behavior of Promises. They're absent from all my books. My web searches aren't finding this detail. I don't have a JavaScript expert in my circle of acquaintances. I agree with others that SO works best when answering specific syntax questions; I don't mean to abuse it. I need another pointer like when I was asking async questions and someone said something like, "Check out Bluebird!" That person is right: Promises are tons better, though I wish I had more documentation.

Comment: I think [Q's documentation](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) might help. It's just another implementation of Promises. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again. I'll read Q's documentation. In the meantime, a follow-on question, please. We agree: "// you DON'T want this" (from your code snippet). What triggers those outputs? It would seem to be no more reachable than "//#3", which follows the return. The statement causing the outputs is syntactically at the same level as `cp(i, j)`, and all that traffic has left `ender` scope. Confused. Thanks.

Comment: The return is inside the Promise callback. So `return` works for the particular function which it stays on. If you have `function one() { console.log(1); return; console.log(2); } console.log(3)` - you will get 1 **AND** 3. The return will stop only from logging `2`.

Comment: I read Q's documentation; it's better than Bluebird's! Thanks for the pointer. I didn't find what I was looking for. Bummer. In my code, let me pretend to be a call to `ender`. I get to an if statement. If I'm i < 3, I go into a line of statements that no matter what `return` me out of `ender`. If I'm otherwise, I skip those statements and a console.log statement marked "don't want this". I don't see a way for me to touch "don't want this". Why does it print? Thanks.

Comment: It will **NOT** return you out of `ender`, it will return out of `.then(function(result, error) {` :)

Comment: Thanks for the note. I understand. Only, does your reply describe the second half of the return statements? I'm expecting that the first half of "return resolve(result)" will return me out of ender (because that's what it does in JavaScript); I think you've referred to the second halves choosing one of the two paths through the callback and into `.then`. Indeed, `reject(err)` and `resolve(result)` do exactly that. If the returns with callback aren't guaranteed to return me from the function, there's some design of the language I need to understand!

Comment: Callbacks **do not return** from the function buddy :) As I said - Promises are **pure** JavaScript, it's not new syntax or something. It's just some kind of *framework* or better said - way of programming. If you want to stop executing the function further on - you should use return.

Comment: Please join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99613/promises-details-for-baldeagle for further discussion :)

Comment: (blush) I see my code with new eyes, now; I understand why the `don't want this` line is executing and I take back my question. And I have it cold: callbacks don't do the return; `return`s do the return. Thanks. It'll be a glorious day when I finally get my code working. Not today, apparently.